# Filemaker Pro display a name instead of id for multiple fields with the same relationship

Tags: mapping, filemaker

I have a two color fields in my Product table. They both are IDs that map to the Color table with a description. I know the idea with Filemaker is to have 2 fields for this, one for display and one to hold the id. However, I can't get a display field to know which colorid to map with, and therefor nothing shows up.

Comment: Can you explain this part: "They both are IDs that map to the Color table"? Do you mean there are **two** relationships between these two tables, one for each product color?

Comment: Yes. I am holding two colors for each product in the form of ids that each map to the color table.

Comment: You haven't answered my question re the relationship/s. It's also not quite clear if the Colors table is really necessary. Does it contain anything besides an id and a (unique) color name? --- P.S. When you reply, address your reply to me so I get notified.

Comment: @michael.hor257k  Yes. There are two relationships. There is one relationship for each ID. There is a separate table for Colors because it is a Master table to keep track of available options, retire them when they are not available, and specify where the colors are available from. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might have your relationship defined with BOTH colorID fields connected to the Color Table. So there is only one relationship that is using two key fields.  If that is what you have then, that is your problem.

To fix it, you will need two relationships.  One for each Color ID field in your Products table. Name them something like "Product Color 1" and "Product Color 2". Then setup your two display calc fields to use those two relationships respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell from your description what's missing in your setup, so let me describe what you *should* have:

Table **Colors**:
**ColorID** - a unique id field (preferably auto-entered serial number);
...more fields describing the color ...

Table **Products**:
... fields describing the product ...
**ColorID1** - a Text or a Number field (match the type to Colors::ColorID); nothing auto-entered;
**ColorID2** - same as ColorID1;

On the Relationships Graph, create two new occurrences of the Colors table and name them "Color1" and "Color2". Define the following two relationships:

```
Products::ColorID1 = Color1::ColorID

Products::ColorID2 = Color2::ColorID
```

Define a value list using the ColorID field from Colors, also showing [some field that helps to select the color]. Attach this list to the two ColorIDx fields on the Products layout.

Place some fields from the Color1 and Color2 occurrences onto the Products layout; make them non-enterable in Browse mode to prevent accidental modification.

Now, when you select a color in either of the two ColorIDx fields, the related fields you have placed on the layout will populate with data from the corresponding related records.

There are some assumptions being made here:

1. each product has *exactly* two colors;
2. it is important to know which color is #1 and which is #2 (otherwise
   we could have used a single relationship and show the two colors in a two-row portal, in no particular order).